# How to combine the two request URL from JSON to get output in volley

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, android-volley

I am having two JSON URLs that I want to combine(Merge) the both URL to get the output in Volley Response.

I have seen created two function of volley, but I want single function to combine both URL to get the output in volley single response.
JSON First

```
{
"status": "200",
"requestType": "productDisplay",
"basePath": "http:\/\/192.168.0.33\/cartwebsite3\/",
"bannerPath": "http:\/\/192.168.0.33\/cartwebsite3\/cdn-images\/banner\/",
"productPath": "http:\/\/192.168.0.33\/cartwebsite3\/cdn-images\/prd\/",
"response": {
    "data": [
        {
            "product_id": "81",
            "seller_id": "2",
            "product_active": "on",
            "product_name": "Samsung Evo Plus 64 GB MicroSDXC Class 10 80 MB\/s ",
            "product_alias": "Memory Card",
            "product_sku": "sa-676",
            "product_manufacturer_country": "India",
            "product_manufacturer": "Samsung",
            "product_min_add": "1",
            "product_max_add": "1",
            "short_description": "Samsung Evo Plus 64 GB MicroSDXC Class 10 80 MB\/s Memory Card",
            "long_description": "Expand the memory capacity of your mobile device or DSLR with this external Samsung MicroSDXC 64 GB Class 10 EVO Plus memory card.",
            "product_quantity": "0",
            "quantity": "20",
            "status": "In Stock",
            "price_id": "75",
            "mrp_price": "2599.0000",
            "selling_price": "1350.0000",
            "offer_percentage": "",
            "product_weight": "0.5kg",
            "offer_selling_price": "1000.0000",
            "offer_selling_percentage": "",
            "offer_selling_start_date": "",
            "offer_selling_end_date": "",
            "shipping_cost": "0.0000",
            "product_images": [
                {
                    "image_id": "91",
                    "product_id": "81",
                    "image_small": "",
                    "image_medium": "",
                    "image_large": "",
                    "original_res": "samsung-evo-plus-64-gb-microsdxc-class-10-80-mbs--971460375462.jpeg",
                    "image_type": "jpeg",
                    "added_date": "1460375462",
                    "added_user": "2",
                    "sort": "0"
                },
                {
                    "image_id": "92",
                    "product_id": "81",
                    "image_small": "",
                    "image_medium": "",
                    "image_large": "",
                    "original_res": "samsung-evo-plus-64-gb-microsdxc-class-10-80-mbs--761460375462.jpeg",
                    "image_type": "jpeg",
                    "added_date": "1460375462",
                    "added_user": "2",
                    "sort": "0"
                },
                {
                    "image_id": "93",
                    "product_id": "81",
                    "image_small": "",
                    "image_medium": "",
                    "image_large": "",
                    "original_res": "samsung-evo-plus-64-gb-microsdxc-class-10-80-mbs--731460375462.jpeg",
                    "image_type": "jpeg",
                    "added_date": "1460375462",
                    "added_user": "2",
                    "sort": "0"
                },
                {
                    "image_id": "94",
                    "product_id": "81",
                    "image_small": "",
                    "image_medium": "",
                    "image_large": "",
                    "original_res": "samsung-evo-plus-64-gb-microsdxc-class-10-80-mbs--561460375462.jpeg",
                    "image_type": "jpeg",
                    "added_date": "1460375462",
                    "added_user": "2",
                    "sort": "0"
                }
            ],
            "basic_info": [
                {
                    "basic_id": "570",
                    "product_id": "81",
                    "option_name": "Capacity",
                    "option_description": "64 GB",
                    "have_connected": "0"
                },
                {
                    "basic_id": "571",
                    "product_id": "81",
                    "option_name": "Class",
                    "option_description": "10",
                    "have_connected": "0"
                },
                {
                    "basic_id": "572",
                    "product_id": "81",
                    "option_name": "Read Speed",
                    "option_description": "80 MB\/s",
                    "have_connected": "0"
                },
                {
                    "basic_id": "573",
                    "product_id": "81",
                    "option_name": "Write Speed",
                    "option_description": "20 MB\/s",
                    "have_connected": "0"
                }
            ],
            "extra_info": [
                {
                    "type": "htmleditor",
                    "htmleditor_extra_title": "Key Features",
                    "ckeditor_content": ""
                },
                {
                    "type": "textfield",
                    "main_header": "Specifications",
                    "field_option": [
                        {
                            "inside_single_title": "General",
                            "basic_opt1": [
                                {
                                    "option_name_extra": "Ideal for",
                                    "option_desc_extra": "men"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "inside_single_title": "Sandal Details",
                            "basic_opt1": [
                                {
                                    "option_name_extra": "Design",
                                    "option_desc_extra": "Logo Detail"
                                },
                                {
                                    "option_name_extra": "Closure",
                                    "option_desc_extra": "Velcro"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "textfield",
                    "main_header": "Sandal Details",
                    "field_option": [
                        {
                            "inside_single_title": "General",
                            "basic_opt1": [
                                {
                                    "option_name_extra": "Sandal Details",
                                    "option_desc_extra": "Sandal Details"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "inside_single_title": "Sandal Details",
                            "basic_opt1": [
                                {
                                    "option_name_extra": null,
                                    "option_desc_extra": null
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "inside_single_title": "Sandal Details",
                            "basic_opt1": [
                                {
                                    "option_name_extra": null,
                                    "option_desc_extra": null
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "category_list": [
                {
                    "category_id": "46",
                    "category_name": "ELECTRONICS",
                    "category_desc": "",
                    "category_image": "",
                    "category_thumbnail": "",
                    "category_image_desc": "",
                    "category_meta_title": "",
                    "category_meta_desc": "",
                    "category_meta_keyword": "",
                    "category_show_hide": "0",
                    "category_vanity": "electronics"
                },
                {
                    "category_id": "62",
                    "category_name": "Computer Accessories",
                    "category_desc": "",
                    "category_image": "",
                    "category_thumbnail": "",
                    "category_image_desc": "",
                    "category_meta_title": "",
                    "category_meta_desc": "",
                    "category_meta_keyword": "",
                    "category_show_hide": "0",
                    "category_vanity": "computer-accessories"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"request": {
    "postData": [],
    "getData": {
        "type": "productDisplay",
        "result": "json",
        "product_id": "81"
    }
}
}
```

JSON 2:

```
{
    "status": "200",
    "requestType": "pinCodeCheck",
    "basePath": "http:\/\/192.168.0.33\/sharpswebsite3\/",
    "product_id": 81,
    "seller_id": 1,
    "pincode": 400010,
    "response": {
        "data": [
            {
                "process": "success",
                "message": "success",
                "pincode": 400010,
                "ships_in": "2 Days",
                "delivery": "5 Days",
                "shipping_charge": "FREE",
                "cod": "1",
                "cod_price": "56"
            }
        ]
    },
    "request": {
        "postData": [],
        "getData": {
            "type": "pinCodeCheck",
            "result": "json",
            "product_id": "81",
            "seller_id": "1",
            "pinCode": "400010"
        }
    }
}
```

Two url:

```
String singleproducturl="http://192.168.0.33/cartwebsite3/qcrest1.0/?type=productDisplay&result=json&product_id="
 String pinurls="http://192.168.0.33/sharpswebsite3/qcrest1.0/?type=pinCodeCheck&result=json&product_id="+productpathid+"&seller_id="+sellerid+"&pinCode="+pin;
```

Anyone Solve this problem glad to appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMO, only way for your issue is that inside onResponse of the first request, you make the 2nd request, then inside onResponse of this 2nd one, you "merge or combine" the 2 JSON objects

Comment: You can't make request 2 URL for a single Request .

Comment: But I want to get the output from both url at same time

Comment: @BNK how can I make inside the onResponse of 2nd one  in volley

Comment: inside `onResponse` of the 1st one, you call like `JsonObjectRequest request2 = new JsonObjectRequest(...)...`. But if you said `at same time`, I don't think it is at the same time, because 2nd will be excuted after 1st finished

Comment: If you want both of them at the same time make changes to your server side.. It is not possible in Volley or in any other Web service call. **You can do it One By One only. 1st finishes then 2nd starts**.

Comment: Suppose If executed second request after completed the first Is it possible to display the output from both url,otherwise  will take time to get the output

Comment: You can see sample code [here](http://pastebin.com/g9a587pS)

Comment: Let me try your code, Thanks.

Comment: what is the requestbody and requestbodytwo

Comment: Ah, that's for POST request, if you use GET, you can set it null

Comment: I got error JsonObjectRequest() in JsonObjectRquest cannot be applied

Comment: Post your code and the detail error message

Comment: I used your code as same example when I make second request URL got  some error like that JsonObjectRequest() in JsonObjectRquest cannot be applied   http://pastebin.com/u1CqEG0d

Comment: Post full error message or post the screenshot of  that error

Comment: @BNKI didn't get the any error showing code under red line see here http://i.imgur.com/kXHH81c.png

Comment: Please, solve this error

Comment: I solved my error BNK Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem and I created two model for two  url then I called it to adapter working fine now

```
JsonObjectRequest request1 = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, requestBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                JSONObject response1 = response;
                JsonObjectRequest request2 = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url2, requestBody2, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // do something with response1 & response here...
                    }
                 }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.i("onErrorResponse", error.toString());
            }

          requestQueue.add(request2);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.i("onErrorResponse", error.toString());
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(request1);
```

Glad to Thank for BNK  Did little mistake I solved,Thanks a lot

Comment: requestQueue wouldn't be accessible inside the onResponse of the the first request `request1`